# Server Side Validation with Flamingo and Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-flamingo-plugin

I have the last WordPress site, with the last contact form 7 and flamingo plugins installed.

It's a simple form, with an email field and a message field.

I want to make a query to the database to check if the email had already sent a previous message into my site.

> Is this possible?.

I'm trying to create a PHP file that makes the query into the database, and I call that file with ajax after the form is submitted.

Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate', 'email_already_in_db', 10, 2 );

function email_already_in_db ( $result, $tags ) {
    // retrieve the posted email
    $form  = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $email = $form->get_posted_data('your-email');

    // if already in database, invalidate
    if( email_exists( $email ) ) // email_exists is a WP function
        $result->invalidate('your-email', 'Your email exists in our database');

    // return the filtered value
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Yes in your functions.php